.NET MAUI Grid. GridUnitType.Star does not specify a proportional size
This code works differently on different platforms.
<Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="6,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Start" RowDefinitions="*, *, *, *" ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto, 60">
    <!--0-->
    <Label Text="111111111" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="111111111" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="111111111" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="111111111" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <!--1-->
    <Label Text="111111111" Margin="2,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="111111111" Margin="2,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="111111111" Margin="2,0,10,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Text="111111111" Margin="2,0,10,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <!--2-->
    <BoxView x:Name="abUpList" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>

on Xamarin platform, it worked as expected. the size of the rows was set by the largest row.

This behavior is not observed on MAUI. And this is how it looks:

How to achieve the same behavior on MAUI as on Xamarin?
Platform: Android
.Net ver 8.0

did you try do use <Grid.RowDefinitions>  </Grid.RowDefinitions> ?

AFAIK, the Grid's height defines the height of the rows when you use proportional sizing. So either try to specify a HeightRequest for the Grid or set its VerticalOptions="Fill".

@Julian on Xamarin it worked without hardcoded HeightRequest and I don't think it's a good practice (hardcoded value). VerticalOptions="Fill" does not solve the question, because if this xml code is used in a list cell, proportional size will not be reached. I just need it to work the same way as on Xamarin.Forms.

@LeandroToloza yes, and it change nothing.

@JackTheHealer I guess you'll need to figure out a way to calculate the actual row heights (e.g. by iterating all children and calculating their bounds), consider any paddings, margins and rowspacing and then dynamically set the HeightRequest from the code-behind by using the product of the height of the largest row by the number of rows.
